# How can I say that in php language if (isset($video_url)&not just only https sting can be found)?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, eco

I have a field inside the WordPress admin area, in the post-new.php section.
I use the latest version of WordPress, as well as the **Advanced Custom Fields** plugin so that I can write out this field in `header.php`.
I use this field for the `og:video` tag, so that I can easily output a secure video url.
The problem is, the default field value is https, and so that I can recall it, the video url must always start with https.
When I click the publish button, the database saves this value, such that the og secure url in a blank state will only be https.
For example:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://www.neocsatblog.info/jwplayer/player.swf?file=https%3A%2F%2F&autostart=true&skinName=newtube&skinURL=https%3A%2F%2Fneocsatblog.info%2Fskinning-sdk%2Ffive%2Fnewtube%2Fnewtube.xml" />
```

This is a problem, because I don't want a blank video in the post for Facebook.
As such, I need to check two things in the header:

1. Firstly: is the field empty?
2. Secondly: Are there any characters in the string after `https://`?

If both the conditions are met, the code should output the url.
Current php code:

```
    $video_url = get_field('video_url');
    if (isset($video_url)) {
      $meta1='<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />';
      $skinURL="https://neocsatblog.info/skinning-sdk/five/newtube/newtube.xml";
      $meta2=' <meta property="og:video" content="https://www.neocsatblog.info/jwplayer/player.swf?file='.urlencode($video_url).'&autostart=true&skinName=newtube&skinURL='.urlencode($skinURL).'" />';
      echo $meta1;
      echo $meta2;
     }
```

Comment: Why I get votedown?
The question is looks like fine to me, thanks for @CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($video_url) && $video_url !== "https://") {
```

Comment: I still get meta in my page:
http://www.neocsatblog.info/vallalkozast-szeretnel-de-meg-nem-multal-el-25/

Comment: Okay, you said in your question the default was "https", but it looks like that's not the case. I've amended my answer.

Comment: I know why.
Becouse I need to use the exact string like:
https://
But thanks buddy, you help me overflow, good point!

Comment: your right, but in my example, I showed the output, the string is on there

Answer (score 1):

Try `if (  (isset($video))   &&   (strpos($address, 'https://') == 0)   &&   (strlen($address) > strlen('https://'))    ) { // do stuff`

Comment: Thx for the answer, but @Chris soulution is worked for me now :)